# Output for specific test case in linked list deletes two numbers randomly

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm working on a linked list program that takes an input for the data of each node like:

> Sample Input:
> 2 18 24 3 5 7 9 6 12

Then it takes each group of even numbers like "2, 18, and 24" and reverses it to be "24, 18, and 2."

It seems to work on a larger scale according to these unit tests, but this particular one outputs:

> 2 3 5 7 9 12 6

Instead of:

> 24 18 2 3 5 7 9 12 6

So it just seems to delete the 24 and the 18 and I'm not sure why. Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node {
  int data;
  node *next;
  node *prev;
  node *curr;
};

class linked_list {

private:
  node *head,*tail;

public:

  linked_list() {
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
  }

  void add_node(int n) {
    node *tmp = new node;
    tmp->data = n;
    tmp->next = NULL;

    if(head == NULL) {
      head = tmp;
      tail = tmp;
    }
    else {
      tail->next = tmp;
      tmp->prev = tail;
      tail = tail->next;
    }
  }

  node* getHead() {
    return head;
  }

  void print_List() {
    node *tmp;
    tmp = head;
    while (tmp != NULL) {
      cout << tmp->data << " ";
      tmp = tmp->next;
    }
  }

  node* reverse_Groups(node* head, node* prev) {

    if (head == NULL) {
      return NULL;
    }

    node *tmp;
    node *curr;
    curr = head;

    while (curr != NULL && curr->data % 2 == 0) {
      tmp = curr-> next;
      curr->next = prev;
      prev = curr;
      curr = tmp;
    }

    if (curr != head) {
      head->next = curr;
      curr = reverse_Groups(curr, NULL);
      return prev;
    }
    else {
      head->next = reverse_Groups(head->next, head);
      return head;
    }
  } 
};

int main() {
  linked_list a;
  int numNodes, i, tempNode;
  
  cin >> numNodes;
  
  for (i = 0; i < numNodes; ++i) {
    cin >> tempNode;
    a.add_node(tempNode);
  }
  
  //a.print_List();
  a.reverse_Groups(a.getHead(), NULL);
  a.print_List();

  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The entire algorithm used by `reverse_Groups` is logically flawed. The expected approach does not require delinking and re-inserting anything, but merely swapping the values between two nodes, resulting in a laughably simple solution: iterating from both ends of the list, towards each other, until both pointers meet, advancing from one to the other, until its reached or until an even number is reached, and then simply swapping the values. The End. P.S. Why does each node have a pointer called `curr`? As Mr. Spock would say: this is not logical.

Comment: *"So it just seems to delete the 24 and the 18 and I'm not sure why."* -- What characteristics do these nodes have that are not shared by the nodes that are working? (The thing that strikes me is that they would be at the start of the list, suggesting a head pointer error.) Hypothesize. Look at your other test cases, and see if your hypothesis is consistent with those results. That could give you something to focus on as you step through your code, comparing the actual result of each step to your expectations.

Comment: You've asked questions before, but don't react when people answer. Not very motivating.

Comment: @trincot I forget to reply to answers but they have helped so far. I didn’t realize people wanted a reply.

Comment: @trincot oh I see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out it was a minor oversight on my end.
The code within `reverse_Groups` returns head when it's done. I was printing the list from the temp variable rather than the head, so it wasn't printing the first two numbers. Once I figured this out, I added a getHead function that returns the correct head after the reverse function finishes.

I just changed the print function to have a head parameter and supply the correct head using the getHead function so that it prints from the right starting point.